# Excel isn't saving VBA reference

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Excel .xlsm file with a bunch of functionality in some VBA Modules/Classes and now I've decided to separate out the code because it will be shared across 4 different sites.

I saved the vba_code.xlsm to a shared location and created my 4 different siteXYZ.xlsm files.

In each siteXYZ.xlsm file I would go to the "Tools | References" menu in the VBA editor and add a reference to the shared vba_code.xlsm at a shared file location \share_location\fileLocation\vba_code.xlsm

At this point, I tested out the functions in siteXYZ.xlsm and everything would work fine.

However, every time I saved siteXYZ.xlsm, closed Excel and then reopened the file it would lose the reference to my vba_code.xlsm file.

How can I keep the VBA references saved with my siteXYZ.xlsm file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After spending hours searching for an answer and trying various methods such as adding a digital signature to the vba_code.xlsm file and trying to programmatically add the reference on Workbook_open I found a forum post describing the problem:

My siteXYZ.xlsm file had no VBA code or macros defined within it so Excel refused to save the VBA Project and as a result did not save the VBA Reference to vba_code.xlsm.

The solution was simple:

Add **ANY** VBA code to the siteXYZ.xlsm and save it.

I just double-clicked ThisWorkbook under the VBA editor and added a function to Workbook_open that doesn't do anything:

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah it's silly isn't it? We want to lockdown the VBAproject of a workbook so that the end user cannot write/insert their own code into the file before it's shared, yet you have to create a module in order to "lock" it.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day !!!!! I'm adding this to allow for better Google referencing if possible : Excel is loosing it's references to VBA libraries after closing and reopening

Comment: My minimalist "solution" is to put this single line in ThisWorkbook:
Sub PreserveReferences(): End Sub

Comment: @6diegodiego9 Add an `Option Private Module` so that sub doesn't show up in the macro list.

Comment: @Toddleson what about "Private Sub PreserveReferences(): End Sub"?

Comment: @6diegodiego9 I agree, `Private Sub` is shorter and also hides it from the macro list

Answer (score 1):

The usual method of achieveing this is by saving your vba_code.xlsm as an addin (XLA or XLAM) and storing it in the shared location, then adding the addin to Excel in your 4 different sites. 
You can also extend this approach by using your own Addin Loader instead of Excel's.
 There is a working example of an Addin Loader at 
http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding code, you can also add a module, user form, or class module. I think the reason for that is that VBA needs one of those four things to determine that a file is a macro-enabled workbook. My guess is that this was done to distinguish between files that contain macros (and therefore have to be enabled) and files that *can* contain macros but do not (e.g. xlsm, xlsb, etc. file with no macros.)

As would be expected, if you later remove the code or modules / userform later and there are no more in the file, Excel will remove your custom name. And the custom name reverts back to VBAProject

Answer (score -1):

Following @nvuono

You need to add some kind of module/reference to the excel file for it to save the references you have added.

```
Private Function addJunkModuleToGetReferencesToSave(ByRef wb As Workbook)

    Set new_module = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_ClassModule)
    new_module.name = "Junk"
    new_module.CodeModule.AddFromString ""

End Function
```