# XLWings - Why do I need to re-check the XLWings reference in VBA

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I had checked the XLWings box in the VBA Editor references yesterday. I was getting an "Object Required" error today and when I had look at the VBA Editor references, The XLWings box was no longer checked.

How do I do this permanently?

Comment: xls files don't save references unless the file has at least 1 line of code in it. It's a weird restriction. Just put `Private Sub PreserveReferences(): End Sub` into a module and the references should stick. For xlsx files, you'll have to save it as xlsm to make sure the code isnt removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel isn't saving VBA reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548861/excel-isnt-saving-vba-reference)